# VueJs: Using component inside another component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue.js

I'm trying to make use of the main component inside another with pre-defined properties.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve, but I'm just getting an empty div as a result.

```js
<template>
    <call-dialog-link
        :id="id"
        :url=url"
        message="Are you sure you wish to remove this record?"
        label="Remove"
        css-classes="alert"
    ></call-dialog-link>
</template>
<script>
    import CallDialogLink from './CallDialogLink.vue';
    export default {
        props: {
            id: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            url: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        },
        components: {
            'call-dialog-link': CallDialogLink
        }
    };
</script>
```

Here's the `CallDialogLink` component

```js
<template>
    <span class="clickAble" :class="cssClasses" v-text="label" @click="clicked()"></span>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            id: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            url: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            message: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            label: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            cssClasses: {
                type: String,
                required: false
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            window.EventHandler.listen('remove-dialog-' + this.id + '-called', (data) => {
                window.location.reload(true);
            });
        },
        methods: {
            clicked() {
                window.EventHandler.fire('top-confirm', {
                    id: 'remove-dialog-' + this.id,
                    message: this.message,
                    url: this.url
                });
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `message`, `label`, `css-classes` dont have property binding on them?

Comment: They are just static props, which I'm passing through to the `CallDialogLink` from within this component. As they are just strings, I don't have to use dynamic binding.

Comment: Then you aren't doing anything wrong, can you just console.log in the `created` hook if the `<call-dialog-link>` component if you are receiving those props?

Comment: I did, but it looks as if it's not being called at all - nothing in the console.

Comment: Try wrapping this up in a `<div>`? also, could you please post the code for the `<call-dialog-link>`

Comment: Updated post with the `CallDialogLink`. When wrapped with `div` - it only returned static properties as `string`.

Comment: `window.location.reload` won't this clear the props?

Comment: It's only called when specific event is triggered from within another component - so it doesn't have any effect on it as it's not called until that event is triggered.

Comment: okay, so with the `div` wrapper, what are the values received?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe there is typo in your code.

```
<template>
    <call-dialog-link
        :id="id"
        :url="url" // didn't open the double quote here
        message="Are you sure you wish to remove this record?"
        label="Remove"
        css-classes="alert"
    ></call-dialog-link>
</template>
```

Comment: You're a life saver! Bloody typos. Thanks very much.

Comment: You were not sure whether it worked, if you knew what you were doing was right, you would have checked over to be sure, but you would come over it with time.