# Vue - Using component inside other component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, single-page-application, vue-component

I am trying to use a `search-bar component` inside my `home.vue` component but I can't figure out why its not working.

**Folder structure**

```
App.vue
 components
   home.vue
   query.vue
   common
    HeaderBar.vue
    SideBar.vue
    SearchBar.vue
```

**App.vue**

script

```
  import HeaderBar from './components/common/HeaderBar'
  import SideBar from './components/common/SideBar'

  export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
      HeaderBar,
      SideBar
   },
```

html

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
   <HeaderBar></HeaderBar>
   <SideBar></SideBar>
   <main class="view">
     <router-view></router-view>
   </main>
  </div>
</template>
```

This above works just fine.

**Home.vue**

script

```
 import SearchBar from './common/SearchBar'

 export default {
   name: 'Home',
   components: SearchBar
 }
```

html

```
<template>
  <section class="home">
    <div class="hero-content">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <SearchBar></SearchBar>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
```

I get those errors:

> [Vue warn]: Invalid component name: "_compiled". Component names can
>   only contain alphanumeric characters and the hyphen, and must start
>   with a letter.
>
> [Vue warn]: Invalid component name: "__file". Component names can only contain alphanumeric characters and the hyphen, and must start with a letter.
>
> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the
>   component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide
>   the "name" option.
>
> found in
>
> ```
> ---> <Home> at src\components\Home.vue
>        <App> at src\App.vue
>          <Root>
> ```

Comment: did you miss the </section> in the template?

Comment: I edited it, just missed it in my question.

Comment: components:  { SearchBar } ?

Comment: You should have a `main.js` somewhere in your project where you specify the names of all the components you are using. It seems like Vue can't recognize what component you want to use. It should be something like this: `Vue.component('app-searchbar', SearchBar);`

See here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html

Comment: This works now, like it should! Thanks.But for my understanding... I imported now the component in main.js `import SearchBar from './components/common/SearchBar'` and then `Vue.component('app-search', SearchBar);` . So now its registered it globally and I can remove the `import` and `components: {}` in my `app.vue` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VueJs: Using component inside another component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42270204/vuejs-using-component-inside-another-component)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By default you have to use it with **kebab-case** in `template` tag.

Register component as of **PascalCase** notation. Use it in component with **kebab-case** notation. Simple as that!

**Case 1 : Default**

```
<template>
 <section class="home">
  <div class="hero-content">
   <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <search-bar></search-bar>
 </div>
 </section>
</template>
<script>
import SearchBar from './common/SearchBar'
export default{
 components: SearchBar
}
</script>
```

**Case 2 : Customized**

Or you want to register it with your way(by applying custom name) just change this code :

```
export default{
 components: {
  'search-bar' : SearchBar 
 }
}
```

**UPDATE**: This answer was provided in reference to vue version 2.x. I am unaware of vue 3.x and haven't read 3.x docs. You can always submit an edit draft for vue 3.x compatible solution. Thanks!

Comment: Edited answer - This is **camelCase**. This is **PascalCase**.

Answer (score 2):

Script of **Home.vue** should be like following

```
import SearchBar from './common/SearchBar'

export default {
   name: 'Home',
   components: {
       'SearchBar': SearchBar
   }
}
```

If you SearchBar component already have a name property values **SearchBar**, the **'SearchBar'** filed name is not required.

Answer (score 2):

May or May not help you, but I did a silly mistake: as

```js
import ServiceLineItem from "@/Pages/Booking/ServiceLineItem";

export default {
  components: ServiceLineItem,
};
```

As it should be like :

```js
import ServiceLineItem from "@/Pages/Booking/ServiceLineItem";

export default {
  components: {
    ServiceLineItem,
  },
};
```